# Get length of Streamreader

Tags: c#, streamreader, memorystream

How can I get the length of a `StreamReader`, as I know nothing will be written to it anymore.
I thought that maybe I could pass all the data to a `MemoryStream`, which has a method called `Length`, but I got stuck on how to append a byte[] to a `MemoryStream`.

```
private void Cmd(string command, string parameter, object stream)
        {

            StreamWriter writer = (StreamWriter)stream;
            StreamWriter input;
            StreamReader output;

            Process process = new Process();

            try
            {
                process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
                process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd";
                process.Start();

                input = process.StandardInput;
                output = process.StandardOutput;
                input.WriteLine(command + " " + parameter);
                input.WriteLine("exit");

                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    int length = 1024;
                    char[] charbuffer = new char[length];
                    byte[] bytebuffer = new byte[length];

                    while (!output.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        output.Read(charbuffer, 0, charbuffer.Length);
                        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
                        {
                            bytebuffer[i] = Convert.ToByte(charbuffer[i]);
                        }
                        //append bytebuffer to memory stream here
                    }

                    long size = ms.Length;

                    writer.WriteLine(size);
                    writer.Flush(); //send size of the following message

                    //send message
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                InsertLog(2, "Could not run CMD command");
                writer.WriteLine("Not valid. Ex: " + e.Message);
            }
            writer.Flush();
        }
```

So, how can I dinamically append a byte[] to a MemoryStream?
There is any way better than this to get the length of `output` so I can warn the other end about the size of the message which will be sent?

Comment: What do you mean by `size`or by `length`?

Comment: When referring to both of them I meant the quantity of bytes/chars on the respective variable.

Comment: I don't understand.. you have the length of the `bytebuffer`.. why not just use that?

Comment: Your code confuses me a lot. Why would you call your `StreamWriter` `input`and `StreamReader` `output`?

Comment: @Simon Whitehead: Because it's just a buffer, the message will be WAY larger than 1024. The idea of this code is basically as follows: I will read `output` step-by-step (each step is 1024 chars), then, on each step I will convert the chars just read to bytes (`MemoryStream`) and append the 1024 bytes to the memory stream. At the end I will have a `MemoryStream` with all my message. Then I can use it to send the message and use the method `Length` to warn the other end about the length/size of the message.

Comment: @btoueg: Because Streamwriter represents the input of Command Prompt and Reader the output.

Comment: @BrunoKlein But you're looping over the stream until `EOF`.. and storing everything in `bytebuffer`.

Comment: @BrunoKlein one more remark, appending to my answer, you could use `m.WriteByte` method to write each byte into the `MemoryStream` at once. This would let you eliminate the `bytebuffer` at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MemoryStream` has [MemoryStream.Write Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.write.aspx) , which writes a byte array to the stream:

```
ms.Write(bytebuffer,0,bytebuffer.Length);
```

So, you can call it to add another portion of bytes to the output stream. However remember, to be able to read from `MemoryStream` after all write operations are over, you'll have to use [MemoryStream.Seek Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.seek.aspx)  to set the position within the current stream to its beginning:

```
//all write operations
ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
//now ready to be read
```

This is the easiest approach. Of cousre, you may dynamically move across the stream, while reading/writing. But that may be error prone.

To get the length of the stream, i.e. `ms.Length`, you don't have to seek the begining of the stream.

I guess, it's worth to note, that if `bytebuffer` is used only to store bytes before copying them into the `MemoryStream`, you could use [MemoryStream.WriteByte Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.writebyte.aspx) instead. This would let you abolish `bytebuffer` at all.

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    ms.WriteByte(Convert.ToByte(charbuffer[i]));
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Does this work for you?

```
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(FilePath);
        long x = sr.BaseStream.Length;
```

Comment: Exception
   Message: "Stream does not support seeking."

Answer (score 4):

Stream has a [Length](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.length.aspx) property, but will throw an exception if the stream doesn't support seek operations.  A network stream for example will throw an exception if you try to read .Length.  In your code, you're processing an input stream of a process.  Consider if that were user input - how would you know the length until you were completely finished reading?

If you're reading a file, you can get the length with stream.Length.

In .NET 4+, you can copy one stream to another with Stream.CopyTo, eg:

```
inputStream.CopyTo(outputStream);
```

You can also load the bytes into memory with:

```
byte[] data;
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    stream.CopyTo(ms);
    data = ms.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example? Because I can't use `CopyTo` in order to copy `output` to `ms`.

Comment: @BrunoKlein both parameters are streams, eg stream.CopyTo(someOtherStream).  Your `output` variable is a StreamReader.  See: https://gist.github.com/25eb147ef11305171b20

Comment: Apparently `StreamReader` does not have a method called `CopyTo`.