# How to find the no. of bytes of a text file without reading it?

Tags: c#, string, streamreader

I have c# code reading a text file and printing it out which looks like this:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(ofd.FileName));
byte[] buffer = new byte[100]; //is there a way to simply specify the length of this to be the number of bytes in the file?
sr.BaseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

foreach (byte b in buffer)
{
      label1.Text += b.ToString("x") + " ";
}
```

Is there anyway I can know how many bytes my file has?

I want to know the length of the `byte[] buffer` in advance so that in the Read function, I can simply pass in `buffer.length` as the third argument.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get length of Streamreader](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637517/get-length-of-streamreader)

Comment: By the way if its a small text file the easiest way to read the data is just `System.IO.File.ReadAllText(file name)` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalltext.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not clear why you're using `StreamReader` at all if you're going to read *binary* data. Just use `FileStream` instead. You can use the [`Length`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.length.aspx) property to find the length of the file.

Note, however, that that still doesn't mean you should just call `Read` and *assume` that a single call will read all the data. You should loop until you've read everything:

```
byte[] data;
using (var stream = File.OpenRead(...))
{
    data = new byte[(int) stream.Length];
    int offset = 0;
    while (offset < data.Length)
    {
        int chunk = stream.Read(data, offset, data.Length - offset);
        if (chunk == 0)
        {
            // Or handle this some other way
            throw new IOException("File has shrunk while reading");
        }
        offset += chunk;
    }
}
```

Note that this is assuming you do *want* to read the data. If you don't want to even open the stream, use [`FileInfo.Length`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.length.aspx) as other answers have shown. Note that both `FileStream.Length` and `FileInfo.Length` have a type of `long`, whereas arrays are limited to 32-bit lengths. What do you want to happen with a file which is bigger than 2 gigs?

Comment: I'd imagine you'd want to open the stream with `FileShare.None` or `.Read` to avoid the file size getting jerked out from under your reads feet, correct?

Comment: Its really confusing when there are so many ways of reading and writing files - BinaryReader, BinaryWriter, StreamReader, StreamWriter and now this FileStream that I never knew about. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @asawyer: Possibly. It depends on whether you want to just detect that or prevent it...

Answer (score 8):

```
System.IO.FileInfo fi = new System.IO.FileInfo("myfile.exe");
long size = fi.Length;
```

In order to find the file size, the system has to read from the disk. So, the above example performs data read from disk but does not read file content.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [FileInfo.Length](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.length.aspx) method.
Take a look at the example given in the link.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine something in here should help.

I doubt you can preemptively guess the size of a file without reading it...

[How do I use File.ReadAllBytes In chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11597295/how-do-i-use-file-readallbytes-in-chunks)

If it is a large file; then reading in chunks should might help